# How do I run a next application on port 80?

Tags: linux, next.js

I'm trying to run a nextjs app on port 80 on arch linux.
I'm getting a permission error even though I'm using sudo.
It seems like no other app is using port 80?

This is `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev -p 80",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start -p 80",
  "lint": "next lint"
},
```

Now when i run `sudo npm run dev`

I get this error message:

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1313:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
    at /home/pera/Desktop/projects/agency/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:45:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.startServer (/home/pera/Desktop/projects/agency/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:19:12)
    at nextDev (/home/pera/Desktop/projects/agency/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:116:23)
    at /home/pera/Desktop/projects/agency/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:130:34 {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}
```

Now when i run `sudo netstat -tulpn`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6463          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17894/Discord --typ 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      585/mongod          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1350/steam          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      317/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27036           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1350/steam          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57343         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1350/steam          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      438/tor             
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      317/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      317/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      317/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35486           0.0.0.0:*                           17894/Discord --typ 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60196           0.0.0.0:*                           17894/Discord --typ 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44070           0.0.0.0:*                           17894/Discord --typ 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*                           317/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           317/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 192.168.0.10:68         0.0.0.0:*                           277/systemd-network 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           317/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27036           0.0.0.0:*                           1350/steam          
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                317/systemd-resolve
```

This is the output. No app is open on port 80?

Comment: EACCESS means you're not running with permissions that will allow opening a privileged port (all ports < 1024).  If another process was using the port, you'd get EADDRINUSE

Comment: @ChrisDodd I'm running it with `sudo` though?